# Find month and date but use any year value

Tags: jquery

I am using this to get a range of dates to determine whether to remove an element , but how can i edit it so i don't have to enter a year value. So is there a way i can set the variables without having to enter the year value ?

```
var findDate = new Date();
var displayModule = new Date("August 2,2015");    //SET STARTING DATE YOU WANT MODULES DISPLAYED
var hideModule = new Date("January 4,2016");   //SET ENDING DATE YOU WANT MODULES REMOVED
if(findDate > displayModule && findDate < hideModule) {

} else {
    $("#InvalidLineup").remove();
    $("#IRviolations").remove();
}
```

Comment: And what should the year be then?

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing `.toJSON` , `String.prototype.slice`

```
 var findDate      = new Date();

 var displayModule = new Date("August 2");    //SET STARTING DATE YOU WANT MODULES DISPLAYED

 var hideModule = new Date("January 4");   //SET ENDING DATE YOU WANT MODULES REMOVED

 if (findDate.toJSON().slice(5, 10) > displayModule.toJSON().slice(5, 10) 
    && findDate.toJSON().slice(5, 10) < hideModule.toJSON().slice(5, 10)) {
    // do stuff

  } else {
    $("#InvalidLineup").remove();
    $("#IRviolations").remove();
  }
```

---

e.g.;

```js
var findDate = new Date();
var displayModule = new Date("July 31");
var hideModule = new Date("August 2");

if (findDate.toJSON().slice(5, 10) > displayModule.toJSON().slice(5, 10) 
        && findDate.toJSON().slice(5, 10) < hideModule.toJSON().slice(5, 10)) {
        // do stuff
        alert("ok")
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @MShack  Can describe _"this is not working at all"_ , create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: @MShack `displayModule` within `if` condition appear missing `.toJSON` at https://jsfiddle.net/asthf7a2/12/ line 8 ? See https://jsfiddle.net/asthf7a2/16/

Comment: ok tested and moved date to beyond today , but its not removing the div https://jsfiddle.net/asthf7a2/19/

Comment: @MShack _" but its not removing the div"_  ? `<div id="InvalidLineup">TEST</div>`  appear to be removed from `DOM` , here , at https://jsfiddle.net/asthf7a2/19/

Comment: use must be only using Chrome , it works in Chrome i see now , but not in IE or FF

Comment: @MShack Try setting year to number corresponding to a year , e.g., 1000 ; `.slice(5, 10)` should return portion of date range utilized within `if` condition https://jsfiddle.net/asthf7a2/21/

Comment: ok this may not be possible them , i reset with a month this year and month next year and doesn't work https://jsfiddle.net/asthf7a2/30/